# Error: no entity to update: app - Firestore Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

This is my very basic Cloud Function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore()

exports.createdNewAccount = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    return db.collection('users').doc(event.data.uid).update({
        "creationDate" : Date.now()
    })
})
```

And I get the error

> Error: no entity to update: app

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Most likely, the document for `event.data.uid` does not exist.  The documentation for [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) states:

> The update will fail if applied to a document that does not exist.

Use [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) instead.

Comment: You might actually want to call set with merge - the doc example is: cityRef.set({
        capital: true
    }, { merge: true })

Comment: thing is, firebase let's you update if doesn't exist whereas firestore doesn't...

Comment: @RonRoyston 'Firebase rtdb' :)

Comment: What's the difference between update and set with merge:true then?

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. It must be that `onCreate` is invoked _before_ the entity is committed. So when you do a search/update, it fails because the entity doesn't exist yet. `set` works ok, because you're actually creating the entity, writing whichever you fields you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar error when testing my app locally with the Firebase emulator. My firebase config file looked like:

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: <FIREBASE_API_KEY>,
  authDomain: <FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN>,
  databaseURL: <FIREBASE_DB_URL>,
  projectId: <FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID>,
  storageBucket: <FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET>,
  messagingSenderId: <FIREBASE_MSG_SENDER_ID>,
  appId: <FIREBASE_APP_ID>,
  measurementId: <FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID>,
};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// for local instances, use the emulator to connect the frontend to firestore & functions
if (location.hostname === "localhost") {
  firebase.firestore().settings({
    host: "localhost:8080",
    ssl: false,
  });

  firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator("http://localhost:5001");
}
```

Turns out my local Firestore database (expected to be running at `localhost:8080`) wasn't being hit. So my cloud functions were trying to write to a non-existent db. The underlying issue was that I also had my backend initializing to a different database:

```
// functions/index.js
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccount.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://other-firebase-project-id.firebaseio.com",
});
```

The solution (originally [adapted from a Fireship tutorial](https://fireship.io/lessons/firebase-emulator-advanced/)) was to remove this [incorrect] re-initialization of the database altogether:

```
// functions/index.js
... 
admin.initializeApp();
...
```

After all, [according to the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?authuser=0#initialize-without-parameters), we can initialize the Firebase Admin SDK without parameters  since *the FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is included automatically in Cloud Functions for Firebase functions that are deployed via the Firebase CLI*.

FWIW, also be sure to set the correct Firebase project on the CLI. Doing so with this allows the Firebase CLI to hook Functions/Firestore to the right project:

```
firebase use <desired-firebase-project-id>
```

If you have multiple Firebase projects, you can list them out with: `firebase projects:list`